# Jenkins pipelines: how to debug the dreaded java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher issue?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I've a comparatively large groovy script for building a multi-platform library, building multiple repositories on multiple build machines. Most of the time it works. Sometimes however I get the dreaded:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
```

issue. This is distinctly not repeatable, and even when it occurs is very inconsistent as to how far the build gets before the issue occurs. I'm wondering if anybody has good suggestions on how to locate the issue.

Now I know the standard problem is the result of `=~` being leaked outside a `@NonCPS` area. I've generally gone through and removed the obvious ones but to no avail, it seems. I suspect when I find the issue it will be obvious, but most will understand how it goes!

I'm wondering if anybody has some good ideas as to how to find such problems? For example is it possible to force the state on every step - so it would consistently fail and ASAP, so at least I could find out where to look?

Comment: I've yet to find an answer to the question, but I did manage to find answers to me specific issues and in doing so finding the situation might be more complex than I'd been led to believe. Basically if you have statements called from parallel, and especially if there are calls to a shell, the completion is handled asynchronously and it seems not just leaked non-serialisable objects are an issue but any use outside NonCPS.
I found I have to stop using not just =~ but also eachMatch in the normal code - latter replaced by a non CTS that returned a list, followed by use of standard each.

Comment: One way I have approached this to to to iteratively add `sleep(1)` step calls, as that appears to force a serialization of the executing pipeline.